# What issues should I be aware of with the Intel Graphics Update Tool for Linux?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel, mesa

I just got a new Kaby Lake laptop (intel hd620). I am wondering whether or not to install the INTEL GRAPHICS UPDATE TOOL FOR LINUX ?

Are there any issues I should be aware of when making my decision?

Comment: From the official site:

"""Linux distributions already include by default an Intel® graphics driver, without needing any extra installation. This tool aims to make the latest Intel® Graphics Stack available before it gets officially released by Linux* OS vendors. Specifically, it benefits those Linux* users of both Ubuntu* and Fedora* distributions wanting to update their graphics subsystems for Intel® platforms."""

So, 1) It's the same drivers, only newer version. 2)  I'd say, not really worth the hassle unless some bug was fixed in the newer drivers.

Answer (score 2):

Without going far down the path of "why" it has been my experience, every time I have installed the proprietary Intel graphics drivers directly, I have regretted it. One reason is during Ubuntu upgrades there have always been issues for me, whether simple (e.g. x.04 -> .10) or major (16.x -> 17.x)

Moreover, removing the package(s) has been a nightmare. If you opt to give them a try I highly recommend making a backup of your system so that rolling back is a simple restore.

Comment: I have had similar experiences, and have read (and recommend) that people should always uninstall proprietary graphics drivers prior to performing system updates.

Comment: But when we uninstall the proprietary graphic drivers what should we install, which drivers?? does is work without drivers?

Comment: I agree with @Mark.

Comment: @lewis4u the system will operate - slowly - as the cpu handles the tasks of doing graphics updates rather than allowing the GPU to do them.

Comment: So do we need to install anything after removing that or just leave it like that?